# Formatting numbering in MS word

Tags: ms-word

Its a simple question.

I have a question with 4 options. 
For example

Q1. How can you eat?

```
a. by mouth
b. by hand
c. by leg
d. by eyes.
```

I want it to format not in the above manner, but as below

Q1. How can you eat?

```
a. by mouth             b. by hand
c. by leg               d. by eyes.
```

How can I do that in MS word please?

Comment: You are probably better served asking the question at an end-user client applications forum such as superuser.com or change your question in a way where it appears to be a developer question, adding information on the developer language used and targeting platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2 by 2 table. You can then hide the table grid so it appears like the formatting you specified above.

Link for creating tables: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2459947/how-to-create-and-customize-tables-in-microsoft-word.html